# Webplayer saves file instead of playing it

Tags: asp.net, flash, firefox, jwplayer, flvplayback

In order to play videos (Flash Format) on the website I use JW Player on my pages. But I seem to have some problems with it.

On certain Firefox browsers when clicking on the player it chooses to download the file instead of playing it in the browser. On the same computer I tried it on Internet Explorer and there my webplayer is showing badly, it stands in the top left corner (whereas it should be in the middle of the page) and flickers a bit.

Because everything is in development the webpage is only available through our servers. In other words, I can't provide you any link with details.

So my question is, why do some browsers download the video instead of playing it?
And is there a possible free alternative to JW Player to play flash videos?

Any comment will be appreciated.
Kind regards,
Floris Devriendt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instaling the latest version of Adobe Flash helped solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I prefrer [flowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) to jwplayer but nevertheless, jwplayer is also a solid player and you should not have this kind of problems with it.

Perhaps your web server do not serve the flv/mp4 files (you do try to play those files I hope) with the correct MIME type, which results in the player not recognizing the files as files it should play.

Comment: Well I am using FLV files generated through the FFmpeg tool. After a person has uploaded a video to the server it will be converted by FFmpeg and convert it. I'm not using FLVTool or something similar which I think might be an issue as it does not store metadata. I have read somewhere flvtool was only needed with large files (which is not the case for me). Does FLVTool do something with the MIME type like storing it?

Comment: MIME type is header in the http response telling the client how it should handle the response. It is a setting configured in IIS per file extension. For FLV it should be "video/x-flv".

Comment: I knew of this before, so I have set it in IIS. There it is not the problem. However could it be that somehow the converted video stores an incorrect MIME type?

Comment: As FFmpeg only converts the video without adding metadata (which is needed for most webplayers) I will try using FLVtool. I will let you know wether or not this solved anything of my problem.

Comment: there is no problem with ffmpeg generated flv files. I used them many times.

Comment: If that would be the case then the problem is not with the files, nor with the player or IIS settings..

When I have acces to the server again I will try different options, like using in FlowPlayer instead of JW Player, adding flvtool capability (doesn't take long) and double checking the MIME type setting in the IIS. But if it is not all this.. then what could be the problem?

Comment: @Variant I think I found the problem. Some computers where it didn't work had not the latest flash player installed. I'm just waiting for an admin to grant me acces to install the latest version and check it out if it works.